# preventScroll when calling Firebaseui start(...)

Tags: javascript, focus, firebaseui

Is there a way to make sure that if and when FirebaseUI calls `focus()` it does so with the `{preventScroll:true}` option?

With FirebaseUI, calling `start(...)` with just the email option will automatically create a text input for email and give it focus. All good.

However, the `focus()` can cause the container and/or document to scroll to the control, which is undesirable if the control is in an element being revealed via animation from off screen e.g. the controls are in a slide-out side-panel in an otherwise scroll-locked SPA.

Obviously it's possible to reveal the container first and *then* call start() to generate and focus the control, just not ideal.

Comment: Looked through the source -- doesn't look like options are ever passed to `focus()`. Filed a feature request.